# Taleo Integration(TCC) - Update Candidate Entity using Candidate service

Tags: taleo

I am trying to generate SQ-XML for updating a field in Candidate Entity. I am not sure how to write it. I know how to write a query for export option. I use below format for export,

Can anyone share the sample of an update query?

Comment: Please share an example of source code with your attempts

Comment: I am not able to add any code it shows some error. I want to update candidate entity using SQ-XML.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
<soap:Body>
    <can:mergeRequest xmlns:can="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01">
        <can:candidate>
            <can:Number searchType="search" searchTarget="." searchValue="123">123</can:Number>
            <can:MiddleInitial>X</can:MiddleInitial>
        </can:candidate>
    </can:mergeRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

You can find some documentation on this in the import section of this pdf:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/fusion-apps/tcwsfp12a-userguide-enus-1648971.pdf